# Jenkins API - Get current pipeline stage of the build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to make my build pipeline more useful and I need a way to terminate previous builds if they are not finished yet.

I have the next Job definition:

```
pipeline {
  stages {
     stage('A'){...}
     stage('B'){...}
     stage('C'){...}
  }
}
```

And I need to terminate all previous builds if they are not in stage'C'.

I use Jenkins API to get previous builds for a particular job:

```
@NonCPS
def cancelPreviousBuilds() {
    def buildNumber = env.BUILD_NUMBER.toInteger()
    def currentJob = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME)
    currentJob.builds
        .find{ build -> build.isBuilding() && build.number.toInteger() < buildNumber && currentStageName(build) != 'C' }
        .each{ build -> build.doStop() }
}
```

So my current stopper is the implementation of `currentStageName` function.
I'm not able to get the name of the stage.
I've already found some code but it does not work well for me:

```
@NonCPS
def currentStageName(currentBuild) {
    FlowGraphWalker walker = new FlowGraphWalker(currentBuild.getExecution())
    for (FlowNode flowNode: walker) {
       if(flowNode.isActive()) {
          return flowNode.getDisplayName();
       }
    }
}
```

FlowNode object does not contain stage name it contains more narrow flow step inside the build.

**So the question is:**
How to get the current stage of previous build for particular Jenkins job?

Answer (score 0):

Given a `FlowNode`, you can check if it is the start of a stage by checking if `node instanceof StepEndNode`. If it is, you can use its `LabelAction` class to get the name of the stage:

```java
    static String getLabel(FlowNode node) {
        LabelAction labelAction = node.getAction(LabelAction.class);
        if (labelAction != null) {
            return labelAction.getDisplayName();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I don't think it's useful for your case, but you can also get it from the node that marks the end of a stage (a `StepEndNode`) by looking up the corresponding start node:

```java
FlowNode startNode = ((StepEndNode) node).getStartNode();
```